# replace data after last delimiter of every line using sed or awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a text file `A.txt`, all lines in which have the same number of fields separated by pipe `|` delimiter.  I need to replace `,` with `|` for the data after the last delimiter of each line.

Example:

```
1,2|3,4|5|6,7,8
1,8|4|6,5,3|4,5
```

Desired output, (only replace `,` with `|` after last delimiter):

```
1,2|3,4|5|6|7|8
1,8|4|6,5,3|4|5
```

How to achieve this using `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} gsub(",", "|", $NF)'
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` sets both the input and output field delimiter as literal `|`
- `gsub(",", "|", $NF)` substitute all (`gsub()`) `,`s with `|` in the last field (`$NF`)

**Example:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} gsub(",", "|", $NF)' <<<'1,2|3,4|5|6,7,8'
1,2|3,4|5|6|7|8

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} gsub(",", "|", $NF)' <<<'1,8|4|6,5,3|4,5'
1,8|4|6,5,3|4|5
```

Comment: what is the complete command to replace all the lines in a file a.txt with the above logic, thanks

Comment: @BuccaneersTampa, just pass file name to awk command, for ex: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} gsub(",", "|", $NF)' A.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
1,2|3,4|5|6,7,8
1,8|4|6,5,3|4,5
```

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a s/^(.*\|[^,]+),([^|]+)$/\1|\2/g; ta' ip.txt 
1,2|3,4|5|6|7|8
1,8|4|6,5,3|4|5
```

- `:a` and `ta` to loop `sed` command until there is a match found
- `^(.*\|[^,]+)` from start of line to `|` followed by non`,` characters. `*` and `+` will try to match as much as possible
- `,` match a comma
- `([^|]+)$` after the comma, there should not be any `|` character till end of line

with `perl`

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane '$F[-1] =~ tr/,/|/; print join "|",@F' ip.txt 
1,2|3,4|5|6|7|8
1,8|4|6,5,3|4|5
```

- `-F'\|'` split input line on `|` and save to `@F` array
- `$F[-1] =~ tr/,/|/;` for last element of array, replace all `,` with `|`
- `print join "|",@F` print the modified `@F` array with `|` as separator

And for some regex magic:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*\|(*SKIP)(*F)|,/|/g' ip.txt
1,2|3,4|5|6|7|8
1,8|4|6,5,3|4|5
```

- `.*\|(*SKIP)(*F)` skip the pattern until last `|`
- then replace all `,` with `|`